# Rolling comparison to create a new colum

Tags: r

I am new to R and working out how to do things I could do in excel in r. I have run into trouble trying to determine how to create a new columns that denotes when the previous value in one column has crossed under the values in a second column. pretty simple time series analysis.

```
val1   val2   
3      2
3      2
1      2 <- Cross under
1      2
1      2
3      2
```

I'd like to append that oput as a column on the data frame like so:

```
val1   val2   Xunder   
3      2      na
3      2      na
1      2      true
1      2      na
1      2      na
3      2      na
```

The code I am trying to do this with is:

```
for(i in 1:length(workingFile)){
    if(workingFile$val1[i] < workingFile$val2[i] &&
       workingFile$val1[i-1] > workingFile$val2[i-1]){
           XUnder<-append(XUnder,TRUE)} 
    else{
           XUnder<-append(XUnder,NA)
        }
}
```

workingFile is a couple thousand rows, and when I run this code, XUnder only has a 10 or so items in the vector so I don't want to add that as a column to the original file. Not sure what is off here or if I am going about this in an inefficient way. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R, very rarely you would need an explicit `for` loop to do things. Many functions in R are vectorised meaning they can handle multiple values and you don't need to pass them values one by one. If the functions are not vectorized there are ways in which you can use `apply` family of functions (or others) which do the same job as a `for` loop.

Here you can use compare `val1` and `val2` directly and use `lag` to compare previous values.

```
library(dplyr)
workingFile <- workingFile %>% 
                   mutate(Xunder = val1 < val2 & lag(val1) > lag(val2))
workingFile
#  val1 val2 XUnder
#1    3    2  FALSE
#2    3    2  FALSE
#3    1    2   TRUE
#4    1    2  FALSE
#5    1    2  FALSE
#6    3    2  FALSE
```

If you need `NA` instead of `FALSE` do :

```
workingFile$Xunder[!workingFile$Xunder] <- NA
```

Comment: Fantastic. That does just what I wanted it to. I must say, the %>% is super powerful. I hadn't learned about that yet. Definitely excited to dig deeper into the language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a base R approach, here is an example of what you could do:

```r
# Creates Data
df <- data.frame(Val1 = c(3,3,1,1,1,3,3), Val2 = 2)

# Finds the first row where the value in the second column 
# is less than the value in the first column
index <- which(df$Val1 < df$Val2, arr.ind = TRUE)[1]

# Make NA's up until the row, puts true, then fills
# the rest of the rows with NA's
col <- c(rep(NA, index-1), TRUE, rep(NA, nrow(df)-index))

# If you want to add the vector to your dataset
df$Xunder <- col
df
#>   Val1 Val2 Xunder
#> 1    3    2     NA
#> 2    3    2     NA
#> 3    1    2   TRUE
#> 4    1    2     NA
#> 5    1    2     NA
#> 6    3    2     NA
#> 7    3    2     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What this code does is it finds the first row that satisfies your condition, then makes a vector with `NA` values until that point, then puts `TRUE`, then continues filling the vector with `NA` values.  Finally it adds the vector as a column in your dataframe.

If you don't want to add it to your dataframe, then just don't run the last line of code